# Can I replace FP50N06 with IRFZ44N?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, automotive, troubleshooting

I own a car audio amplifier which uses a DC to DC converter having a MOSFET of the type of FP50N06. However, after prolonged use, the three of the positive rail switching MOSFET cooked and smoked.

I was trying to replace that MOSFET, however, the FP50N06 is not available in my location so I had decided to replace it by readily available IRFZ44N MOSFET.

Here is the question: Can I replace it without major consequences? Thank you for your answer.

Based on your suggestions, here are the datasheets for the two MOSFET's:

- [FP50N06](http://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=4474)
- [IRFZ44N](http://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=3398)

Don't care about their difference in power. :)

Comment: It would be polite to link to the datasheets for both parts. That would encourage people to look at them to help you. It would be better practice to show why you think this replacement might work, and ask about any aspects you  are unclear on. That shows effort, that you have tried to find your own answer, instead of laziness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see pretty much the same performance from the IRZ44Ns. That is to say, they may well cook too.

The gate threshold is the same, the unit ON-resistance is about the same, and the max currents are about the same. So the IRZ44Ns should work just about as well as the original MOSFETs. And you do remember how well they worked, right?

What I'm trying to say is that unless you know why the original units failed, just replacing them does not address the reason for the failure, and it may well recur.

Comment: Sir I was an IT student but I want to repair my Amplifier on my own, I knew a lot of things about basic electronics, however, I failed many times in troubleshooting an amplifier.

Only the positive rail of the SMPS are cooked, but the negative rails are still in good condition. All the capacitors of both rails are working, also the fuse of the input power (+12V) did not tripped. So why is that sir? Thank you.

Comment: The on resistance *is not* the same. If this was already a way over spec'd part it would be one thing, but this is likely not true in a power supply this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkJhomelOlimon - Sorry, I'm not psychic. Obviously the upper units cooked because they got hot. This suggests that the gate drive circuitry (and n-type MOSFETs used on the upper rails need special bootstrapped drivers) is getting flakey.

Comment: @bss36504 - 17.5 mohm @ 25 A vs 22 mohm @ 50 A is too close to say, particularly since the OP has no idea what current the FETs were actually running at. Or do you know for certain what those values are?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast where are you getting 22mohm? The FP50N06 is 9 mohm max at Id=20A, Tj=25C, the IRFZ44N is 17.5 mohm at Id=25A, Tj=25C. That's a significant difference in RDS for very similar test conditions. And you're right, we don't know how much current is actually flowing in the FETs, but I'd rather assume its 50A and pick an appropriate part rather than assume it's lower and under-spec the replacement.

Comment: Well here it is. Amplifier runs at +12VDC, which is stepped up by using PWM IC which drives the MOSFETs. The output rectified voltage of the transformer is about +30V, -30V and the output RMS of the amplifier is 300W. I hope that you can determine the current where the FETs running at. (Note that 3 pairs of FETs are there in each rails)

Comment: @bss36504 - http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/RFP50N06-99743.pdf Where are you getting _your_ numbers from?

Comment: Ooh i done f*'d up. Carry on, while I go over here and hide. I had the wrong datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, Mark, but you just have no idea what you're doing, and are completely out of your depth.

Comment: @bss36504 - That'll do it every time (grin).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yeah, I should have RTFM a *little closer* haha

Answer (score 4):

The IRFZ44N has

- A higher \$Rds_{on}\$
- A lower \$I_{d\_max}\$
- A Lower \$V_{ds\_max}\$

than the FP50N06.

> Don't care about their difference in power.

Well that's silly. Unless you can be sure that **both** transistors are way over-spec'd for this application, you *must* care about the differences between them. The \$Rds_{on}\$ in the IRFZ44N is 95% higher than the FP50N06 (at \$V_{gs}=10V\$).

Are you certain that at the current levels this FET will be operating under that you can afford almost 2x the power dissipation? The only thing that is for certain is that the IRFZ44N will produce significantly more heat than the FP50N06.

I suggest finding a better FET, there are literally thousands of them in that package that would do the job at least as well as the OEM solution, if not better. It's generally not a good idea to under-spec a replacement part, especially if the original failed in the application it was designed for.

Comment: Thank you sir. I guess that something's wrecked the rail. Maybe slugs or trimmings of metal casing short circuited the positive rail, causing the MOSFETs to cook. I will try to replace the 3 positive as well as the three negative rail N Channel MOSFETs by IRFZ44N then I look forward to see the result. Thanks again.